# Is there a scaling function in SVMlight?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm, svmlight

The `LIBSVM` [guide](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf) states that data sets should be scaled to a certain range before running SVM on them. In Appendix B of the guide, they show a LIBSVM function `svm-scale` that does the scaling. Is there an equivalent function for `SVMlight`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no. You have to standardize the data by yourself. Just keep in mind that use the mean and std of training data in test data scaling.

Comment: Thanks @lennon310. Forgive my ignorance, but could I use `LIBSVM`'s `svm-scale`'s output for `SVMlight`? If not, how is the standardizing done? (and what did you say I should keep in mind?) Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Cheshie, yes of course you can use svm-scale. But why not use the whole libsvm instead of svmlight:)

Comment: My question was if the format of the output matches SVMlight... and yeah, you're right. I just felt that SVMlight was more user-friendly, but I guess I'll have to do as you say. Thank you @lennon310! :)